# PHP call static workaround for PHP 5.2

Tags: php

Is there are way to get __callStatic, or similar, functionality in PHP 5.2?

I'm finishing a PHP Framework and need to use this functionality for a Database ORM class. So for example you can use the code below to get data from column 2 and column 4 of the database table i.e. by declaring methods dynamically according to what you want (like rails I guess).

```
Class::find_by_col2_or_col4();
```

I have already done this in PHP 5.3 and it works perfectly, but I'm trying to do the same for those using PHP 5.2.

Or is there some other way to retrieve the name of the static method and arguments using PHP 5.2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in a static capacity. Technically speaking Rails, CakePHP, etc don't call these types of dynamic methods statically. Not to get in a philosophical debate, but if backward compatibility is a requirement, you could shift your paradigm and use `__call()`. In which case you would call with an object like `ModelObject->find_by_col2_or_col4`. Of course I understand that's probably not what you wanted to hear.

It's PHP, there's probably some kind of way to hack it, but I don't believe a native method exists.

Comment: Thanks Jason,

I've been looking for a way to get this done for PHP 5.2 but couldn't seem to find any hack or workaround. Also can't find any hacks to inspect what static functions are being called.

Anyway, the functionality that relies on __callStatic is only required for the Forms and Database ORM modules, so the need is not platform-wide.

I guess for users that can't switch to 5.3, they'll have to make do with 5.2 compatible functionality. They'll still be able to do everything, but not in coolest ways e.g. Database ORM.

Cheers.

Comment: Good luck man. Sounds like what your doing is pretty neat and probably worth the upgrade.